# Improve this search engine detecter with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code which detects which search engine and what search term has been used:

```
if (document.referrer.search(/google\.*/i) != -1) {
    var start = document.referrer.search(/q=/);
    var searchTerms = document.referrer.substring(start + 2);
    var end = searchTerms.search(/&/);
    end = (end == -1) ? searchTerms.length : end;
    searchTerms = searchTerms.substring(0, end);
    if (searchTerms.length != 0) {
        searchTerms = searchTerms.replace(/\+/g, " ");
        searchTerms = unescape(searchTerms);
        alert('You have searched: '+searchTerms+' on google');
    }
}
```

That actually works, but unfortunately it doesn't work as expected sometimes.

Sometimes if the referrer was even not google i get an alert with the search term as : ttp://www.domain.com ( without H at the start ) i think that may lead to the bug.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried leveraging existing JS URL parsing schemes?  It might save you a bunch of time.  For example:

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri

Comment: Thanks that was totally a huge time saver! Also if you don't mind, how to know if the referrer is in the same current domain or not ( to exclude same domain referrers ) ?

Comment: Offhand, I don't, sorry.  But I'm glad you were able to leverage the ParseURI stuff -- it seemed like a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

It's cutting the "h" off because `q=` was not in the referrer string.  So your `start` variable is -1.  Then you add 2 to that to get your `searchTerms` var with a substring.  You need to check for `start` to be equal to -1 and return.

I also think your "google" string detection is not bulletproof, I would rather do something like this...

```
var ref = document.referrer;
var pcol = ref.indexOf("://") + 3;

if(ref.indexOf("google.com") == pcol || ref.indexOf("www.google.com") == pcol) {
  // It is google
}
```

One last thing, you should use `decodeURIComponent` instead of `unescape`.

Comment: Thanks, but i think that'd exclude the international google extentions like .ca .co.uk .jp

Comment: @David Very good point, you could remove the `com` from the string literals